# To forbid react-dev-extension in chrome

Tags: reactjs

Are there any ways to forbid react-dev-extension in chrome?
In other terms I want that react-dev-extension wouldn't connect to React module

Comment: You're running interpreted code on someone else's hardware, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution after had read the sourcecode of extension and react.
Even though it's not beautiful, it solves the task.

```
if (
  window &&
  window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ &&
  typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === 'object'
) {
  Object.keys(window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__).forEach((key) => {
    delete window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__[key];
  });
}
```